# Why are controls being lost on postback?

Tags: development, web-part

I am having a really frustrating time with this.  I have tried starting from scratch with a new project even, and still it happens.  Basically, I have a webpart, with a label and a button in it.  When I click the button, I want it to write some text to the label (this is a very basic example which when I get it working will obviously be changed to do something useful).  Every time I click the button however, I get a NULLREFERENCEEXCEPTION (object reference not set to an instance of an object), which when I debug shows that the label has been set to null, i.e. not initialised.  Below is my code.  If anyone could help me out with this I would be eternally grateful.

```
namespace BusinessReports
{
    [Guid("8aba453e-5083-454b-95c3-3a63a2050601")]
    public class TT001 : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
    {    
        protected Label lbl = null;
        protected Button btn = null;

        public TT001()
        {
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            Label lbl = new Label();
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
            btn.Text = "Click";
            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl.Text = "clicked";
        }
    }
}
```

The webpart loads into SharePoint just fine, but throws the error when you click the button.

Answer (score 3):

in your `CreateChildControls` method you are creating a new Label and Button and assigning them to local variables `lbl`, and `btn`, rather than the class level fields `lbl`, and `btn`.

This means when you get to the `btn_Click` method, you've never actually set `lbl`

try this instead:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();

    lbl = new Label();
    btn = new Button();
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    btn.Text = "Click";
    this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: That's got it!  I feel a bit of a fool for not spotting that, but am so relieved to have it working, I'll get over it!  Thank you SO much for saving me from more hours of frustration.